# The Powered Up app won't connect to my Technic Hub

Tags: technic, motor, powered-up, control-plus

I have recently bought a Technic Hub and four Powered Up L motors, but currently I only put two motors into the B and D ports of the hub. I downloaded the Powered Up app to a tablet and used the "Create" function to create a custom controller profile.

After I pressed the green button on the hub, there is a progress bar and the light on the hub is flashing white, blue, and red. After the progress bar reached 100%, the screen on my pad returned to that of the controller interface. However, I could not get the motor to move and the light on the hub is off.

The programming block I use is this (but I selected the B port):

[image]

Could you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: It looks like a virtual joystick on the screen is needed to move it, did you try that? I will do more trouble shooting with set 42099 later.

Comment: Do you mean the blue icon with a joystick symbol? How do I incorporate it?

Comment: Perhaps if you run the program, a UI on the screen that looks like a remote with a joystick will show up. I have Lego Boost and that's what happens whenever you run the program. Try pressing the yellow start button to run the program.